# Formula for increment text value

Tags: google-sheets, unique, string-formatting, vlookup, number-formatting

I have the column with a combination of text and number - T-00001. I would like to have the formula to get T-00002, T-00003, and so on. I tried to use CONCATENATE("T-",RIGHT("T-00001",5)+1) but I get T-2, without 4 nulls. Is it possible to receive it in the correct format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to drag it use:

```
=TEXT(ROW(A1), "T-00000")
```

if not, use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(ROW(A1:A), "T-00000")))
```

[image]

if you plan empty rows use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(COUNTIFS(A2:A, "<>", ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), "T-00000")))
```

[image]

for fixed range:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(20), "T-00000"))
```

[image]

to increment ony with each unique:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(TEXT(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))}, 2, 0), "T-00000")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you see me test spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_yZ5EFDcU3yX_e61_iP2QYff-ifrKhK_2PesxzmxJQ/edit#gid=794023511
I would like to have a check - IF ID is the same as the previous line, the ID2 should not be changed.

Comment: @MaksymKatsovets answer updated. see last formula

Comment: Hi,
Is it possible to convert formula for excel?

Comment: @MaksymKatsovets it's surely possible, but I am not familiar with excel syntaxes at all. apologize